# Project Server OData

Tags: javascript, project-server

How to get value of project cost or custom field?

```
// Initialize the current client context.
var projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();

// Get the projects collection.
projects = projContext.get_projects();

//Other Part
var enumerator = projects.getEnumerator();

var enumerator = projects.getEnumerator();

while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
   var project = enumerator.get_current();

    console.log(project.get_cost()); //Not Work! How  get field Duration, for example?

    var html = "<tr><td>" + project.get_name() + "</td></tr>";
     $("#tblProjects").append(html);
}
```

Comment: nice to put language in tag

Comment: using PSI or CSOM you can achieve that in no time.Later you can append that to your table.If you are ok with that, I can paste code below

Comment: @Sasidharan : Do you have any links to books on PSI or CSOM reference apart from MSDN SDK?